# How do I add autocomplete to git aliases?

Tags: git, bash, posh-git

I have setup git autocomplete using the `git-autocomplete.bash` file which works for standard commands and simple aliases (`co = checkout`), but I have a longer alias defined in my `.git-config` file that I would like to autocomplete branch names on and I cannot find how to do this.

I am on Windows Server 2012 R2 running git 2.10.2.windows.1

My alias looks like this:

`mstage = "!git checkout stage && git pull && git reset --hard && git merge $1 --no-commit"`

where `$1` is a branch name - I'd love this to autocomplete

Comment: Which operating system are you using @Braydie

Comment: I'm on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: What 'git-autocomplete.bash'? If you mean 'git-completion.bash', which version? The latest one should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here we have two options for windows operating system:

**msysgit**

1. Download and place `git-flow-completion.bash` in home directory (`~/` in
   msysgit shell)
2. Add a `.bashrc` file to your home directory with the following line
   (or add this line to existing `.bashrc` file):

   source ~/git-flow-completion.bash

**Cygwin**

1. Download and place `git-flow-completion.bash` in

   `%CYGWIN_INSTALLATION_DIR%\etc\bash_completion.d`
2. Rename it to `git-flow`

   you can autocomplete as following: `git flow init` etc.

Comment: Brilliant that works. I've been using posh-git in PowerShell and for some reason it's not working there. Wonder if there's anything that can be done there..?

Comment: Thank you and accept it as a answer if it works for you @Braydie

Answer (score 2):

@Rohit Poudels answer works if you are using bash on Windows. If you are using PowerShell, currently the only way to enable this autocomplete is to change posh-git manually after installing.

I changed the GitTabExpansion.ps1 file in posh-git, similarly to what is [outlined on the repo](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/257).

More specifically, I added `$line = $line -replace '^git mstage ', 'git checkout '` as the first line in the function `TabExpansion`  which will in effect will treat my alias as equivalent to `git checkout` and tab expansion will then behave as expected